# How to change an object's generic type dynamically in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My Spring batch code reads and writes data to Database. I have two batch job classes and both the jobs have reader logics (almost same) with different pojo generic type (like Pojo1 and Pojo2) at below reader object.

```
FlatFileItemReader<DifferentPojoName> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
```

Now I would like to create a generic reader logic in a separate @Component class. So that both the job classes will make use same reader logic.

But question is how can I change the Pojo type dynamically there in the reader object?

Please suggest.

Comment: Post code of your job. Typically you would create some generic method with `T` type and inside logic you would just `FlatFileItemReader<T> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();` and T would be the Pojo class.

Comment: @ michalk; True, but how do I pass T (specific pojo type) from the two job classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to change an object's generic type dynamically in Java?

Generics are compilation features to improve the code typesafety.
so it is just not possible.

The cleaner way would be to declare distinct `FlatFileItemReader` beans with  the generic it needs.
The `@Bean` annotation may be helpful there.

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Foo> readerFoo(){
  return new FlatFileItemReader<>();
}

@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Bar> readerBar(){
  return new FlatFileItemReader<>();
}
```

And now inject them where you need :

```
@Autowired
FlatFileItemReader<Bar> readerBar;

@Autowired
FlatFileItemReader<Foo> readerFoo;
```

Comment: Worth noting that it will work for Spring version 4+.

Comment: Or create an interface that both inherit from that can get passed

Comment: @ davidxxx; Thanks, I have already those beans and the reason why I didn't autowire is that I would want to see it in just java way not with as spring way. But anyway your answer should work. But can you let me know with just java way?

Comment: @michalk. Sure but it is not a new thing :) (december 2013) : https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics

Comment: @Sairam Vinjamuri  That is the Java way. Beans are not simple objects. These are objects managed by the Spring Container. To make them working in a Spring container, you have to make Spring aware of them. And `@Bean` achieves that.

Comment: @davidxxx and @michalk; Thank much! Question is answered.